# UIDatePicker crashing application

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, swift2

In my app I have a `textfield` form that i want populated from a date picker, I have assigned the date picker as the input view for the textfield and a `datePickerValueChanged` func to change the text of the textfield when the picker is changed. My issue is that when clicking off the data picker in the app, the whole app crashes with

> 'terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'

any ideas? Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var startDatePickerField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let startDatePicker:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    startDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
    startDatePickerField.inputView = startDatePicker
    startDatePicker.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(popoverTableViewController.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

}

func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    startDatePickerField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

This is all contained in the class for the view controller "popoverTableViewController". Thanks!

Here is the crash report from log:

> 2016-07-28 12:50:00.956 ClockIn_v2[5935:2049267]
>   -[ClockIn_v2.popoverTableViewController startDateDidBegin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff571c10720 2016-07-28
>   12:50:00.961 ClockIn_v2[5935:2049267] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[ClockIn_v2.popoverTableViewController startDateDidBegin:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff571c10720'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe5986b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010f4b124e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010fec7904 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fddfed5
>   ___forwarding_** + 1013   4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fddfa58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x000000011027aaf0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>     6   UIKit                               0x00000001103fda69
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     7   UIKit                               0x00000001103fdd82 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
>     8   UIKit                               0x0000000110d5b196
>   -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 297    9   UIKit                               0x000000011048d780 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 286
>     10  UIKit                               0x0000000110d5af94
>   -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 49   11  UIKit                               0x000000011048d82f -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140    12 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000110d5ae63 -[UITextField
>   resignFirstResponder] + 136   13  UIKit
>   0x000000011048d4bf -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 358  14 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000110328dae
>   -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 138   15  UIKit                               0x0000000110d59d2e -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51     16  UIKit
>   0x00000001107af37b
>   -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 206     17  UIKit
>   0x00000001107b2b46
>   -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 3823   18  UIKit
>   0x00000001107a081d -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget
>   _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 57   19  UIKit                               0x00000001107a85b4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109  20 
>   UIKit                               0x00000001107a613b
>   _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 540     21  UIKit                               0x00000001107a539d -[UIGestureRecognizer
>   _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1177  22  UIKit                               0x00000001107911f2 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1013   23  UIKit
>   0x0000000110790db5 -[UIGestureEnvironment
>   _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 521     24  UIKit                               0x000000011078ff2c -[UIGestureEnvironment
>   _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 286    25  UIKit                               0x00000001102e945c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3989    26  UIKit
>   0x00000001102967a5 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 281  27  UIKit
>   0x0000000110a632c3 **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3303
>     28  UIKit                               0x0000000110a5be75
>   __handleEventQueue + 4879     29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fdff5d1
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fde485c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fde3d46 __CFRunLoopRun + 918     32  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010fde3754 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     33  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000114629a71 GSEventRunModal + 161  34  UIKit
>   0x0000000110278e9c UIApplicationMain + 159    35  ClockIn_v2
>   0x000000010eec96df main + 111     36  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001136a968d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: cab you show the full crash report

Comment: Ive added the log contents on crash to the post, is that what you mean?

Comment: Is your `popoverTableViewController` being properly initialized? If the instance that contains the selector is nil you will get an exception thrown.

Comment: see the error `startDateDidBegin` the function is missing

Comment: Ok thanks, what should be in my startDateDidBegin function? I'm assuming I link this from the storyboard as IBAction??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of adding action using

```
startDatePicker.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(popoverTableViewController.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Open it in Assistant editor, open storyboard in one part, right click on your date picker, in the list of events, click on "Value Changed" (it will show a little '+' sign when you will hover upon the empty hole in front of it) and extend it to your "popoverTableViewController.swift" file.